Can N-valued logic (for N = 3 or more) be the basis of mathematics?
I have some questions related to multivalued logic. I am new to this forum, (I study mathematics) so I would be grateful to any useful advice. I am doubtful on even posting this question on Philosophy SE.
Can 3 valued logic (True, False, Indeterminate) be the basis of mathematics? If accepted so, can normal mathematics like proofs, relations, sets, function, calculus, analysis and algebra be developed? Much of modern math is based on the bivalence principle and the law of the excluded middle??
Also, what if fuzzy logic (developed by Zadeh) and set theory and fuzzy arithmetic are used as the foundations of mathematics? What would be the demerits to this approach? And can it be applied fields of study like physics? And probably new fields like QM and GR?
Apart from other questions, my questions is can we develop normal mathematics from this framework??

I would suggest researching constructivist mathematics. It's similar to what you're proposing. It takes all "normal" logical foundations, but does not accept the law of the excluded middle. So it doesn't explicitly have n truth values, but simply says that there's not necessarily only true and false, so it's a little more general. You get a lot of interesting results, but a lot of the motivation lies in the proof theory. The proofs often require much more "construction" and "agency", making them feel more intuitive.

Are you asking out of idle curiosity or do you have in mind some specific characteristics of mathematics that traditional logic can't handle?

The Q is about maths, but in digital electronic logic 3 states are routinely used. See tri-state or Three-state logic. These are real, manufactured circuits. And in computer programming a system can be modelled to have any number of discrete states.

One can, in principle, base a version of mathematics on any non-classical logic, but some are more popular than others. Constructive (intuitionistic logic) and inconsistent mathematics (paraconsistent logic) are the most popular. Mathematics based on fuzzy logic has been developed, see Bělohlávek et al., Fuzzy Logic and Mathematics, ch. 5, but is not very popular. I have not seen versions with finitely many truth values explored in the literature.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic


Can 3 valued logic (True, False, Indeterminate) be the basis of
mathematics?

In mathematics, given a function f, the truth value of y = f(x) can informally be said to be to indeterminate if x is not in the domain of f. There is, however, no need invent a third possible truth value of "indeterminate." It is enough to simply say, in the language of set theory, that x is not an element of the domain of f -- a true-or-false statement.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
